# Simplify the cubic root of cube assuming real and positive variable

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials, assumptions, factorization

I know this is very simple but I couldn't find a reasonable solution for it in the archive. It seems that my Mathematica does not take into account the assumptions when it wants to simplify the expression. Here is the thing

I have the following expression for `gs1`

```
gs1=-((Sqrt[3] (1/(1 + \[Alpha]^3))^(1/3))/2^(
  2/3)) + (r^3 (1 + Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]])^(3/2) + (
   3 Sqrt[3]
     r^3 (-1 + \[Alpha]^3) (Cos[\[Theta]] + Sin[\[Theta]]) Sin[
     2 \[Theta]])/(4 (1 + \[Alpha]^3)))^(1/3)
```

If you copy and paste the above expression in your Mathematica notebook you will see that it contains the cube root of `r^3`, which upon assuming that r is positive must be simply `r`. So I simplify it using the following command

```
gs2 = Simplify[gs1, Assumptions -> r > 0]
```

However, it doesn't do anything. This is very trivial and it should easily take `r^3` out of the cube root and make it `r` but it doesn't.

I was thinking that maybe this is not the correct way of doing it so I tested it with a very simple expression

```
Simplify[Surd[x^3, 3], Assumptions -> x > 0]
```

and it gives `x` as the result.

Following the answer of @Nasser, I found something strange.

```
ClearAll[a, b, r];
term = (r^3 b + (r^3)/2)^(1/3);
Simplify[term, Assumptions -> r > 0]
```

this does not simplify the term, however, when I edit the term and eliminate the denominator by multiplying by `0.5`, instead of dividing by `2`, I get what I am looking for

```
ClearAll[a, b, r];
term = (r^3 b + (r^3)*0.5)^(1/3);
Simplify[term, Assumptions -> r > 0]
```

Here is the screenshot also

[image]

Comment: You'll get an idea of the issue from this simple example `ClearAll[a, b, r];
term = (r^3 b +  (r^3) /2)^(1/3); Assuming[r > 0, Simplify[term]]` and you can see it does not factor `r` as you wanted. Using `ExpandAll` does not help here `Assuming[r > 0, ExpandAll[term]]`. One way is to force `Collect`, like this `ClearAll[a, b, r]; term = (r^3 b +  (r^3) /2); term = Collect[term, r^3]^(1/3)
Assuming[r > 0, Simplify@term]` and now it works. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qs7p.png)

Comment: It is strange. For me it worked and it factored r out.

Comment: Yes, `ExpandAll` worked for your specific example. But `ExpandAll` will not works for all cases, as the above example shows.

Comment: No, what I mean is that following your example if I assume r>0 and simplify your term, I get r factored out without the need to use the Collect command.

Comment: This is strange. Which version do you use? Could you please post a screen shot? Here is mine  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hDfkm.png)

Comment: I use Mathematica 11.3 on Windows 8.1Pro. Yes, of course. See the edited post.

Comment: Did you type exactly what I have? Not Surd or anything else. Because I just tried it on 11.3 also, and get same result as 12. It does not simplify. Here is screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xC5yx.png)

Comment: I tried it again but I couldn't get (very funny). But I found out that the problem is in the presence of the denominator.

Comment: `the problem is in the presence of the denominator.` Yes. This is what I said in my answer :)

Comment: @Nasser Aha ok sorry I overlooked it. You are right.

Comment: @Nasser I used your expression in the Mathematica of my colleague (Mathematica 11.2 on Windows 10) and without any problem it factored out r. No further manipulation was needed indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping `gs1` with [`ExpandAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpandAll.html):

```
Simplify[ExpandAll @ gs1, Assumptions -> r > 0]
```

> (-Sqrt[3] (1/(1 + α^3))^(1/3) +
>    r ((6 Sqrt[3] (-1 + α^3) Cos[θ]^2 Sin[θ] +
>       6 Sqrt[3] (-1 + α^3) Cos[θ] Sin[θ]^2 + 
>       4 (1 + α^3) (1 + Cos[θ] Sin[θ])^(3/2)) /
>   (
>      1 + α^3))^(1/3))/2^(2/3)

```
TeXForm[%]
```

> $\frac{r \sqrt[3]{\frac{6 \sqrt{3} \left(\alpha ^3-1\right) \sin (\theta ) \cos ^2(\theta )+6 \sqrt{3}
>    \left(\alpha ^3-1\right) \sin ^2(\theta ) \cos (\theta )+4 \left(\alpha ^3+1\right) (\sin (\theta ) \cos
>    (\theta )+1)^{3/2}}{\alpha ^3+1}}-\sqrt{3} \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{\alpha ^3+1}}}{2^{2/3}}$

You can also use `ReplaceAll` to force the transformations you want:

```
gs1  /. Power[a_. x_^k_ + b_. x_^k_, c_] :> x ^(k c) (a + b)^c

TeXForm @ %
```

> $r \sqrt[3]{\frac{3 \sqrt{3} \left(\alpha ^3-1\right) \sin (2 \theta ) (\sin (\theta )+\cos (\theta ))}{4
>    \left(\alpha ^3+1\right)}+(\sin (\theta ) \cos (\theta )+1)^{3/2}}-\frac{\sqrt{3}
>    \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{\alpha ^3+1}}}{2^{2/3}}$

Comment: Thanks for the response. It works but why it shouldn't understand my assumption without ExapndAll command?

Comment: @KratosMath, i am puzzled too.

Answer (score 1):

This is on version 12, windows 10.

Another workaround is to force collect on `r^3` on the second term

```
term1 = -((Sqrt[3] (1/(1 + α^3))^(1/3))/2^(2/3));
term2 = (r^3 (1 + Cos[θ] Sin[θ])^(3/2) + (3 Sqrt[3] r^3 (-1 + α^3) (Cos[θ] + Sin[θ]) Sin[
        2 θ])/(4 (1 + α^3)));
gs1 = term1 + Collect[term2, r^3]^(1/3)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Assuming[r > 0, Simplify[gs1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A quick experiment shows that M does not collect factors out when one term has something in the denominator. Compare

```
ClearAll[a, b, r];
term = (r^3 b +  (r^3) /2)^(1/3);
Assuming[r > 0, Simplify@term]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above did not work. But this works

```
ClearAll[a, b, r];
term = (r^3 b + r^3 )^(1/3);
Assuming[r > 0, Simplify@term]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So to force `r^3` to be factored out, one can use `Collect`

```
ClearAll[a, b, r];
term = (r^3 b + r^3/2 );
term = Collect[term, r^3]^(1/3);
Assuming[r > 0, Simplify@term]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And this is basically what I did for your more complicated example.

Comment: Nice, it works, but shouldn't it be treated as bug? I check `LeafCount`, there is no logical reason on why `Simplify`works in one case, but not in another.